# Angular ui-select-match placeholder automatically setting width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I have `<ui-select-match placeholder="Select areas...">{{$somestuff}}</ui-select-match>`

The input box with the placeholder is getting its width set to 10px; automatically no matter what I do (as seen in the picture below). I have no idea why this is happening, and if I touch anything on the page or even adjust the size of the browser window it goes back to displaying the entire placeholder.

Does anyone know why this is happening? In the console I can see that it is says: element.style: width: 10px; but there is no reference to any css file where that is coming from, and I haven't touched any css files anyway.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 10px width you are taking about is added by angular ui-select library. One solution you can do is override the width of the textbox by using css !important property.

```
.ui-select-container{
      width:50px!important; //put whatever pixel value you need.it wont change
}
```

ui-select-container class is added by the library after the ui-select is rendered.

Comment: thank you for your response. My only question is why wasn't this happening before and also why does it go back to normal if adjust the size of the browser window or click on any other inputs on the page?

Comment: Angular-ui-select is wrapper around the library called select2. In select2 library the width is given as some value by default. This value is added by javascript thats why you see element.style: width: 10px;. In most of the example in their website you can see that they override some values through css. Its standard procedure. Ultimately its left to you to add whatever value you want to see in the browser.

Comment: and changes its value whenever you adjust the screen because it renders the library every time you make changes. The library has a $watch function within, which is triggered and the value resets